# AppCompat Gives Error after giving Firebase dependency ver 11.2.0

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, build, dependencies

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at

> android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at
> android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
>   at
> android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
>   at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.(CustomBar.java:95)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.(StatusBar.java:67)
>   at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
>   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:146)
> Copy stack to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

This warning is not related to firebase in any way. If your project have custom views, this type of warning is common. Just rebuild the project and refresh the layout to see the preview again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why , But when I use the latest vesions of the Suport libraries I get error I think some part of the library not supporting the latest version when we use the firebase Auth UI